# Unable to start network, <IP> is already in use for device eth0, but its not

Tags: networking, rhel, arp

A weird issue after we migrated some of our servers to a new DC. We assigned new IPs to all the machines and all the servers are working fine except one. It is not picking up the new IP address and its failing with the following message when I try to restart network with the new IP, new GW and the new netmask in the `ifcfg-eth0` file.

```
Bringing up loopback interface:                                      [OK]
Bringing up interface eth0: Determining if ip address 10.80.3.2 is already in use for device eth0
Error, some other host already uses address 10.80.3.2
                                                                      [FAILED]
```

After I added `ARPCHECK=no` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` the `eth0` comes up fine with the new IP address, but then we will have no network access. The machine will behave as if the network is dead. We are 100% sure that the IP address 10.80.3.2 is not active on any other machines.

I am not very good with networking. Can anyone throw some light to where I can fix this?

P.S:- It is a VMware VM.

Comment: It might be interesting to have a look at what is happening when the interface is set up (and when you try to reach some other system): `tcpdump -i eth0 -n host 10.80.3.2`

Comment: This is what I am getting and nothing else. I `ctrl c` d it.
`tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 byte`.  By the way, with network up (by ARPCHECK=yes), I tried SSHing to the same 10.80.3.2 machine  and I logged into the same server. A loop :)

Comment: Have you tried `arping 10.80.3.2`? I believe it's used by the distro to check for duplicate IP.  It may shed some light on your predicament.

Comment: Go to one of the other machines on the LAN and `ping 10.80.3.2`. then check its ARP cache to see the MAC address of the device with the duplicate IP.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I rebooted the machine before checking the ARP cache and its working fine now. I will investigate when I get some free time after the migration tasks are over. The `ifcfg-eth0` file still have the `ARPCHECK=no`.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue> If so please answer and close the question.